What are the meanings behind these names?
Why are these people called by these names:

Baal Shem Tov / בעל שם טוב
Chazon Ish / חזון איש
Baba Sali / באבא סאלי
Steipler / סתייפלאר
Chofetz Chaim / חפץ חיים
Vilna Gaon / וילנא גאון
Baal Hatanya / בעל הטניא
Levush / לבוש
Aruch Hashulchan / ערוך השולחן


If you can think of any other names - that would also be appreciated!


Shalom L'olam


Don't forget the Chozeh of Lublin and the Shpoler Zeide

2,5,7,8,9: Title of their best known book. 4,6: city of origin.
